# How to implement a search engine in my site with mongoose and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, search-engine

I want to implement a search function that will search for the user in a partial or full way, for ex Bob = Bob Herald, Bob Granger.

I am new to node js please help.

Comment: There is [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) and there is [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). You should look at both closely and understand the differences then determine which is the best fit for your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find` from mongoose with `$regex` condition, like:

```
collection.find({
  'fieldToSearch': {
    '$regex' : 'searching text'
  }
})
```